# converting a world space normal map to a tangent space normal map

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

Let's say I only have a World space normal map texture , is it possible to convert that texture to a tangent space normal map , without the original mesh ?

For example :

[image]

Is there an algorithm that could convert the normals on the left to the normals on the right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without the mesh you do not have the TBN matrices describing the local TBN space the texture is used in so the answer is:

**NO you can not** convert global normals into mesh local coordinate system without the mesh itself.

**However** in case of uniform distribution of texels (area inside a texture and its correspondent area projected onto mesh has the same ratio anywhere on the mesh) then you can estimate the mesh surface positions (by integration) so if the mesh has some uniform tesselation grid which can be inferred it is possible but the result would be just rough and the process itself would be much much harder then using original mesh...